# n-n relation in Backpackforlaravel: doesn't delete corresponding items

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-backpack

I'm having troubles with a n-n relationship in my Backpackforlaravel app. I have Registrations and Sessions, the setup in the model looks like this:

Registration:

```
public function sessions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Session::class);
}
```

Session:

```
public function registrations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Registration::class);
}
```

So the setup seems to be fine, and I also have a registration_session table in my database.
What I want to achieve is, that whenever a Session gets deleted, I want to delete all the entries in the registration_session table, but also all the Registrations. I thought the deletion of the entries in the registration_session table maybe is a standard, but it didn't delete them when I deleted a session. In order to achieve both, I did the following in the destroy function of my SessionCrudController:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->crud->hasAccessOrFail('delete');

    foreach ($this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->registrations as $registration) {
        $registration->delete();
    }
    DB::table('registration_session')->where('session_id', $id)->delete(); //really required?

    return $this->crud->delete($id);
}
```

I have the feeling that I'm doing things way more complicated than I should, so I would appreciate any recommendations.

Update: this is how I store the data initially in the table...the information is coming from a form, so it's not added in a CRUD panel:

```
        DB::table('registration_session')->insert([
            'registration_id' => $reg->id,
            'session_id' => $sesId
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Backpack or Laravel don't concern themselves with deleting related entries, because they assume your Database layer will handle it. With most DBMSs you can specify such rules, and Laravel makes it easy to do so in their migrations. Take a look at [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) in the Laravel docs, it's pretty easy to build your migration in such a way that any time one item gets deleted, the related items will to, using "cascade":

```php
$table->foreignId('user_id')
      ->constrained()
      ->onUpdate('cascade')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```